# How to get a visa appointment with the German consulate earlier?

Tags: visas, germany, applications

I'm traveling to Germany in October 2018. No slots are available now (July). Can anyone please let me know how to get someone's canceled appointment? Or is there any other way to get the appointment as soon as possible?

Comment: Additional information would be helpful, at which consulate are you trying to get an appointment?

Answer (score 1):

Anusha, I assume from your name that you are applying from India. Visa applications at any of the German consulates in India take less than a week to process, from the time you apply at the VFS office. You therefore have enough time to apply for a visa for an October departure.

Comment: I don’t believe that this answer addresses the question of what can be done if there is no availability for an appointment for a visa application.

Comment: My interpretation of the OP's statement was that there were no appointments available in July. Even if the appointment is in Sept (a month before departure) there isn't a problem. In my experience appointment times in India don't stretch beyond a month in peak season.